# Cant understand the meaning of this two phrases

Tags: javascript, object, pass-by-reference

```js
let spaceship = {
  homePlanet : 'Earth',
  color : 'red'
};
let tryReassignment = obj => {
  obj = {
    identified : false, 
    'transport type' : 'flying'
  }
  console.log(obj) // Prints {'identified': false, 'transport type': 'flying'}
 
};
tryReassignment(spaceship) // The attempt at reassignment does not work.
spaceship // Still returns {homePlanet : 'Earth', color : 'red'};
 
spaceship = {
  identified : false, 
  'transport type': 'flying'
}; // Regular reassignment still works.
```

Let’s look at what happened in the code example:

We declared this spaceship object with let. This allowed us to reassign it to a new object with identified and 'transport type' properties with no problems.
When we tried the same thing using a function designed to reassign the object passed into it, the reassignment didn’t stick (even though calling console.log() on the object produced the expected result).
When we passed spaceship into that function, obj became a reference to the memory location of the spaceship object, but not to the spaceship variable. **This is because the obj parameter of the tryReassignment() function is a variable in its own right.** **The body of tryReassignment() has no knowledge of the spaceship variable at all!**
When we did the reassignment in the body of tryReassignment(), the obj variable came to refer to the memory location of the object {'identified' : false, 'transport type' : 'flying'}, while the spaceship variable was completely unchanged from its earlier value.

Comment: @Bergi I'm asking for passed for reference objects, can't understand how exactly this works.

Comment: But you just perfectly explained in your question how it works!

Comment: @Bergi Ok. Can you say why the body of the tryReasignment() function, has no knowledge of the spaceship variable?

Comment: Both are objects, each located in different places in memory... there's no relationship between them.

Comment: @rigan Because it uses only the `obj` variable, not the `spaceship` variable. Both might (initially) hold the same object, but they're separate variables as you already said in the question, not one variable pointing to the other.